# Material UI dark theme isn't applied to the background

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have my react application where I want to apply Material UI `darkBaseTheme`. Without it, part of my app looks like this:

[image]

After I wrap all the html stuff in my `render()` with:

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Having those imports:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'; // add
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'; // add
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';
```

It looks like this:

[image]

So it changed `RaisedButtons`. I know it shouldn't change html ones. But why didn't it change the background to dark? Is there a way to do this, or do I have to do it manually without Material UI?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to include the `<CssBaseline />` component at the root of your app as this is what deals with changing the background colour on the body.

[Docs](https://material-ui.com/style/css-baseline/#page)

Comment: Adding CSS baseline caused all the spacing in my app to change. My circles are circles without CSS baseline and ellipse with it. Is there any fix?

Comment: I love that it is buried in `Components > Utils`, far away from anything having to do with styles.

Comment: Be sure that `<CssBaseline />` is inside of `<ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}`. Strange that it's not mentioned in [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#main-content). I see that it's shown as per couple of answers below. 

Answer (score 39):

I had a similar issue. The body background was not changing when I switched to `dark` mode.

**Solution:**

Move your `CssBaseline` inside `MuiThemeProvider`. Otherwise the body background won't change when you use type `dark` in your theme.

```
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <App />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 16):

**MUI v5 Update**

You can change the background to a dark color by setting the `mode` property [to `dark`](https://mui.com/customization/dark-mode/#main-content), and include the `CssBaseline` which sets the `backgroundColor` of the `body` element:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
  },
});
```

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <CssBaseline />
  <Content />
</ThemeProvider>
```

If you want to use a custom color for the background:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: 'gray',
    },
  },
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This helps. Thanks. I was using the `type` property from the previous versions.

Comment: How would I be able to do mode: 'dark' using TypeScript? The only solution for now is @ts-ignore, but I would like an official solution.

Comment: docs should include we need cssbaseline

Answer (score 0):

Guys dark mode doesn't work as it supposes to. You must import the correct syntax which is

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
```

When you expect the program to import that automatically it imports wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a problem on importing `<CssBaseline />.`

I was doing this:

```
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material";
```

But the solution was importing like this:

```
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
```